# Error when trying to run Watir test through Fitnesse

Tags: windows, testing, selenium, watir, fitnesse

I've recently been trying to run the following tutorial:
http://raveendran.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/watir-integration-with-fitnesse/

However I when I attempt to run the test in Fitnesse, it just sticks on "running test" without ever doing anything. I have tried to replace some of the Syntax, formatting etc but I just get the same result. Does anyone know how successfully implement this tutorial?

Many thanks for any help provided.
Matt

Comment: Can you post more info?  The test is probably crashing when FitNesse tries to launch it - which may be a problem with a path, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember doing that. It was tough to set up correctly. I can't remember much about it, but there was a fixture that helped me at [Faucets](http://faucets.rubyforge.org/). Good luck.